# mysql full group by error when creating a new query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which I am struggling with.
I need to show who the user is (u.username) but am getting a mysql full group by error

```
select ass.client_id,
sum(ass.smsQuantity),
recent.created,
recent.createdBy,
sum(acc.credits) credits,
u.username
from accountSmsSubscriptions ass
left join sms_accounts acc on acc.client_id = ass.client_id
left join (select client_id,max(id) id from accountSmsSubscriptions group by client_id) 
cur on cur.client_id = ass.client_id
left join accountSmsSubscriptions recent on recent.id = cur.id
left join users u on u.id = ass.createdBy
where ass.client_id = 242
group by ass.client_id
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you to include all the non-aggregated columns in your group by clause, i.e. everything that isn't summed.

It also suggests that the sql_mode 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' has been enabled on the server. This is a GOOD thing because you will otherwise get indeterminate results - so don't disable it!